# Crystal Reports 8.5 showing multi-values from parameters on report footer

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

In Crystal Reports 8.5 when I have setup a parameter for multi-value the user enters 90654-90658A. Normally I would use Join() but being that this is not just text but numeric I have tried a few things but with no results.

```
    Local NumberVar i;
Local NumberVar j;
Local StringVar param_values;

if 0 in {?CPT} then
  "CPT #s: All CPTs"
else
(
  for i := 1 to UBound ({?CPT}) do
    for j := Minimum ({?CPT}[ i ]) to Maximum ({?CPT}[ i ]) do
      param_values := param_values + "," + CStr (j, "#");
  "CPT #s: " + Mid (param_values, 2)
)
```

This works fine for 90654-90658 but when the user selects 90654-90658A it fails.

Also the selection criteria will not pass to SQL in the query sent to SQL with the correct where clause. Meaning there is not indication that I am even asking for a where. It should show in the select for sql a where table.data >= '90654' and table.data <= '90658A'

I am lost as to where I am going wrong with this.  Any help would be great this is my first time seeking an answer on this site  but I have not received any help on this request.

Thanks

Comment: Is the parameter field a string or a numeric?

Comment: The parameter field was set to string but then I had to change to numeric to get the values to show but that is a new issue but as stated above 90658A I would take to be a string and it must be so because the code I have fails when I enter the range 90654 to 90658A

Comment: So, the parameter is 1) `numeric`, 2) accepts range values, and 3) accepts multiple values.  Is that correct?  At minimum, you need to change it to a `string`.

Comment: Yes that is correct. The above formula works but nothing is sent to SQL in the where clause. so the parameter shows 90654,90655,90656,90657,90658 but my report shows blank. And if someone adds 90658A it fails completely.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a similar query with the Xtreme.mdb database, referencing the `Customer` table.  I created a string, range parameter that accepted multiple values (i.e. multiple ranges).

When I supplied it with two ranges, the follow query was generated:

```
 SELECT `Customer`.`Postal Code`
 FROM   `Customer` `Customer`
 WHERE  (
          (`Customer`.`Postal Code`>='04000' AND `Customer`.`Postal Code`<='04999') OR
          (`Customer`.`Postal Code`>='55000' AND `Customer`.`Postal Code`<='55999')
        )
```

As you can see, Crystal Reports will build the necessary `BETWEEN` or `>= <=` statements.

In you situation, try:

```
( "0" IN {?CPT} OR {TABLE.FIELD} IN {?CPT} )
```

You could adapt your formula field to display the values of the parameter, if you want.

Comment: Thank you for the information.  I tried as you suggested and received the following message in my record selection formula editor (a string is required here.) ( 0 IN {?CPT} OR {CLBALCPT.CPT} IN Blinking cursor shows here{?CPT} )

Answer (score 0):

I do appreciate everyones input but I was able to work through the problem. For the record selection I put in the following.  {TABLE.FIELD} in CStr({@MinCPT}) to CStr({@MaxCPT}). This pulled the range after I created two formulas. One MinCPT and the other MaxCPT.  Here is the formula.  Left (ToText (Minimum ({?CPT})),2 ) & Mid (ToText (Minimum ({?CPT})),4 ,3 ) and the same for Max.  The report works fine now.

Thanks Again.